# How to verify a stylus smart contract?

Tags: arbitrum, rust, blockscout, stylus

I have deployed the `Counter` contract to the [Stylus testnet](https://stylus-testnet-explorer.arbitrum.io/address/0x3480c0B42c6fAC108160b63B9516584fb9b8971a/contracts#address-tabs). However, looking at verification options, it looks like only Solidity & Vyper is supported.

Is there a way to verify a Stylus (rust-based) contract?

The code is here:

````rust
//! Implements a hello-world example for Arbitrum Stylus, providing a Solidity ABI-equivalent
//! Rust implementation of the Counter contract example provided by Foundry.
//! Warning: this code is a template only and has not been audited.
//! ```
//! contract Counter {
//!     uint256 public number;
//!     function setNumber(uint256 newNumber) public {
//!         number = newNumber;
//!     }
//!     function increment() public {
//!         number++;
//!     }
//! }
//! ```

// Only run this as a WASM if the export-abi feature is not set.
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "export-abi"), no_main)]
extern crate alloc;

/// Initializes a custom, global allocator for Rust programs compiled to WASM.
#[global_allocator]
static ALLOC: wee_alloc::WeeAlloc = wee_alloc::WeeAlloc::INIT;

/// Import the Stylus SDK along with alloy primitive types for use in our program.
use stylus_sdk::{alloy_primitives::U256, prelude::*};

// Define the entrypoint as a Solidity storage object, in this case a struct
// called `Counter` with a single uint256 value called `number`. The sol_storage! macro
// will generate Rust-equivalent structs with all fields mapped to Solidity-equivalent
// storage slots and types.
sol_storage! {
    #[entrypoint]
    pub struct Counter {
        uint256 number;
    }
}

/// Define an implementation of the generated Counter struct, defining a set_number
/// and increment method using the features of the Stylus SDK.
#[external]
impl Counter {
    /// Gets the number from storage.
    pub fn number(&self) -> Result<U256, Vec<u8>> {
        Ok(self.number.get())
    }

    /// Sets a number in storage to a user-specified value.
    pub fn set_number(&mut self, new_number: U256) -> Result<(), Vec<u8>> {
        self.number.set(new_number);
        Ok(())
    }

    /// Increments number and updates it values in storage.
    pub fn increment(&mut self) -> Result<(), Vec<u8>> {
        let number = self.number.get();
        self.number.set(number + U256::from(1));
        Ok(())
    }
}
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what is verification? It's something not related to the blockchain per se, but about blockchain explorers. And the only explorer I could find was https://stylus-testnet-explorer.arbitrum.io/ , which utilizes Blockscout explorer.

I'm not very familiar with Blockscout, but it's for "EVM based blockchains". Stylus is only loosely EVM-based - they call it "EVM+". Therefore, Blockscout doesn't support Stylus contracts (or maybe, if you get lucky, it might support the Solidity Stylus contracts, don't really know).

So I would say this is a question more for the Blockscout development team: will they support EVM+ blockchain contract verifications.

Or maybe someone sets up another explorer where verification is supported. But I would say that is not likely to happen in near future, since it would require very customized EVM+ compatibility code.